# The "Turn screen off after X minutes" not working well in 16.04

Tags: screen, thinkpad

This is a problem I remember from back in the 10 series of Ubuntu, but it's back in 16.04: When I set the screen to turn off after, let's say, 2 minutes it works for a while but then it doesn't turn the screen off anymore. It gets dark, but the backlight is still on. This always happens after the laptop wakes up after suspend. If I reboot it works like expected for while again. I'm on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon where this has worked perfectly until 16.04. Any ideas how to get this back to be working reliably.

Comment: Does the 'Display Power Management' section of the Xscreensaver work any better?

Comment: I have used GNOME 3.20 for while and it works much better there so this is a Ubuntu/Unity issue. Would really like to figure it out.